# How to assign values of variables with index

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, indexed-variable

I'm trying to plot the following function

$V(\{r_j\})=\sum^n_{i<j,j=1}
\frac{1}{|r_i-r_j|^2}$

in Mathematica.

For the expression of this function, I wrote

```
v[n_] := Sum[
   Boole[i < j] (1/Abs[r[[i]] - r[[j]]]), {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, j - 1}];
```

When I give the n-values, this expression works with the error "Part specification r[[1]] is longer than depth of object."

To plot, I wrote

```
vv[r1_, r2_] := v[2] /. {r[[1]] -> r1, r[[2]] -> r2};
Manipulate[Plot[vv[r1, r2], {r1, 0, 10}], {r2, 0, 10}]
```

The code I wrote seems to work if I replace every r[[i]] with ri every time for different n-values.

I want to improve the expression for more general cases. How can I assign values of r[[i]] and r[[j]], and fix the error above?

Comment: E.g. use `r[i]` instead if `r[[i]]`. The latter calls i-th element of a list (while `r` has a head `Symbol` not `List`, hence the error message). The former defines a new object with "index" i.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I fixed the error now. But how to assign values to a list of elements?

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[vv]
vv[r_List] := Total[1/Abs[Subtract @@@ Subsets[r, {2}]]]

Manipulate[Quiet @ Plot[vv[Array[r, n] /. r[1] -> r1], {r1, 0, 10},
     AxesLabel -> {"r[1]", "vv[r]"}],
 {{n, 3}, 1, 20, 1},
 Delimiter, 
 Dynamic[Grid[Table[With[{i = i}, {HoldForm@r[i], Slider[Dynamic[r[i]], {0, 10}],
       Dynamic[r[i]]}], {i, 2, n}]]], 
 Initialization :> {Do[r[i] = RandomReal[10], {i, 2, 20}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very illuminating. May I ask how "{{n, 3}, 1, 20, 1}" in the plot works?

Comment: @Victoria, the parameter `n` controls the length of the input list `Array[r,n]`. It is initialized to 3 and takes integer values from 1 to 20.

Comment: Why it is initialized from 3, not from 2?

Comment: @Victoria, no particular reason.